# Getting profiled user groups from ALS(Alternating Least Squares) algorithm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-platform

We are using ALS (Alternating Least Squares) method in our Google Cloud spark environment to recommend some companies to our users. For making the recommendation we are using this tuple (`userId`, `companyId`, `rating`) and the rating value consists of a combination of the user's interests such as clicking the company page, adding a company to favorite list, making an order from the company, etc. (our method is very similar to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/recommendations-using-machine-learning-on-compute-engine#Training-the-models))

And the results are pretty good and works for our business case, however, we are missing 1 thing which is important for us.
We need to learn which users are grouped as similar interests(a.k.a neighbors), Do you know is there any way to get grouped users from pyspark's ALS algorithm?
So we would be able to tag the users according to that grouping

**Edit:**

I've tried the answered code in the below but the results are strange, my data is paired like this (`userId`, `companyId`, `rating`)
When I run the below code, it groups the users with no common `companyId` in the same `clusterId`.
For example, one of the results of the below code is:
`(userId: 471, clusterId: 2)`
`(userId: 490, clusterId: 2)`

However users `471` and `490` have nothing in common. I think there is a mistake here:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("user_clustering")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setCheckpointDir('checkpoint/')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_IP = sys.argv[1]
CLOUDSQL_DB_NAME = sys.argv[2]
CLOUDSQL_USER = sys.argv[3]
CLOUDSQL_PWD  = sys.argv[4]

BEST_RANK = int(sys.argv[5])
BEST_ITERATION = int(sys.argv[6])
BEST_REGULATION = float(sys.argv[7])

TABLE_ITEMS  = "companies"
TABLE_RATINGS = "ml_ratings"
TABLE_RECOMMENDATIONS = "ml_reco"
TABLE_USER_CLUSTERS = "ml_user_clusters"

# Read the data from the Cloud SQL
# Create dataframes
#[START read_from_sql]
jdbcUrl    = 'jdbc:mysql://%s:3306/%s?user=%s&password=%s' % (CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_IP, CLOUDSQL_DB_NAME, CLOUDSQL_USER, CLOUDSQL_PWD)
dfAccos = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=TABLE_ITEMS)
dfRates = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=TABLE_RATINGS)
print("Start Clustering Users")


# print("User Ratings:")
# dfRates.show(100)
#[END read_from_sql]

# Get all the ratings rows of our user

# print("Filtered User Ratings For User:",USER_ID)
# print("------------------------------")
# for x in dfUserRatings:
#      print(x)

#[START split_sets]
rddTraining, rddValidating, rddTesting = dfRates.rdd.randomSplit([6,2,2])
print("RDDTraining Size:",rddTraining.count()," RDDValidating Size:",rddValidating.count()," RDDTesting Size:",rddTesting.count())
print("Rank:",BEST_RANK," Iteration:",BEST_ITERATION," Regulation:",BEST_REGULATION)

#print("RDD Training Values:",rddTraining.collect())

#[END split_sets]

print("Start predicting")
#[START predict]
# Build our model with the best found values
# Rating, Rank, Iteration, Regulation
model = ALS.train(rddTraining, BEST_RANK, BEST_ITERATION, BEST_REGULATION)


# print("-----------------")
# print("User Groups Are Created")
# print("-----------------")

user_features = model.userFeatures().map(lambda x: x[1])
related_users = model.userFeatures().map(lambda x: x[0])
number_of_clusters = 10
model_kmm = KMeans.train(user_features, number_of_clusters, initializationMode = "random", runs = 3)
user_features_with_cluster_id = model_kmm.predict(user_features)
user_features_with_related_users = related_users.zip(user_features_with_cluster_id)
clusteredUsers = user_features_with_related_users.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
orderedUsers = clusteredUsers.takeOrdered(200,key = lambda x: x[1])

print("Ordered Users:")
print("--------------")
for x in orderedUsers:
    print(x)


#[START save user groups]
userGroupSchema = StructType([StructField("primaryUser", IntegerType(), True), StructField("groupId", IntegerType(), True)])
dfUserGroups = sqlContext.createDataFrame(orderedUsers,userGroupSchema)

try:
    dfUserGroups.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=TABLE_USER_CLUSTERS, mode='append')
except:
    print("Data is already written to DB")


print("Written to DB and Finished Job")
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of dfRates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have trained your model you can get the users feature vector using [userFeatures()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=userfeatures#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.userFeatures)

After that, you can calculate the distance between the users using some distance function or use a clustering model like [KMeans](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=kmeans#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.train)

So if the model is already trained:

```
user_features = model.userFeatures().map(lambda x: x[1]).repartition(50)

number_of_clusters = 10

model_kmm = KMeans.train(user_features, number_of_clusters, initializationMode = "random", runs = 3)

user_features_with_cluster_id = model_kmm.predict(user_features).zip(user_features)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I call model.userFeatures() , it returns an array with first item is the related users(which I want), second item is an array with strange values such as below, so I didnt understand anything, what I actually want is an array with first item is the related user, second item is the distance. Is something like that possible?

array('d', [0.35871902108192444, -0.531110942363739, 0.48245128989219666, 1.0261790752410889, -0.40107470750808716, -0.03667597472667694, -0.21021370589733124, -0.31594404578208923, 1.4115242958068848, -0.06862092763185501])

Comment: Yes the first item is the userId and the second is the user's feature vector (Like it is implied by using  "userFeatures"). This feature vector represents the autolearned features of this user from the ALS model. Now you need to calculate the distance between different users yourself, based on this vector, or use clustering like I showed in my answer.